# Pytest fail exit code 1, (github actions)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, pytest, github-actions

I have a github repository that has a file `Test_app.py`. I am running a pytest on the file in github actions and keep getting the error message: `E   botocore.exceptions.NoRegionError: You must specify a region.`

I then specify the region in my file as: `dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name= 'eu-west-2')`. And get the following error when I execute a pytest:

```
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.6, pytest-6.2.0, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: D:\a\cloudresumechallenge-BackEnd\cloudresumechallenge-BackEnd
collected 0 items

============================ no tests ran in 0.31s ============================
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

This is my lambda code:

```
import boto3
import json
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name= 'eu-west-2')
table= dynamodb.Table('zacresumetable2')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    response= table.update_item(
    Key= {'URL': 'zacresume.com'},
    UpdateExpression= "SET visits = visits + :increase",
    ExpressionAttributeValues= {':increase': 1},
    ReturnValues= "UPDATED_NEW"
)
    return {'statusCode': 200,
            'body': json.dumps('visitsUpdated'),
            'headers': {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
print("UPDATING ITEM")
print("response")
```

and this is the workflow for the pytest:

```
name: Python package

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: windows-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        python-version: ['3.8']

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python ${{ matrix.python-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-python@main
      with:
        python-version: ${{ matrix.python-version }}
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        python -m pip install flake8 pytest
    - name: Install boto3
      run:  pip3 install boto3
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      run: |
        pip install pytest       
        pytest
```

folder structure
SAMFOLDER
-.aws-sam
--build
--build.toml
-samconfig.toml
-template
-lambda
--requirements
--Test_app
sample Test:

````
Requirement already satisfied: pytest in c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.8.6\x64\lib\site-packages (6.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: toml in c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.8.6\x64\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (0.10.2)
Requirement already satisfied: attrs>=19.2.0 in c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.8.6\x64\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (20.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: colorama in c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.8.6\x64\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (0.4.4)
Requirement already satisfied: iniconfig in c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.8.6\x64\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (1.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pluggy<1.0.0a1,>=0.12 in c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.8.6\x64\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (0.13.1)
Requirement already satisfied: packaging in c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.8.6\x64\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (20.8)
Requirement already satisfied: py>=1.8.2 in c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.8.6\x64\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (1.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: atomicwrites>=1.0 in c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.8.6\x64\lib\site-packages (from pytest) (1.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing>=2.0.2 in c:\hostedtoolcache\windows\python\3.8.6\x64\lib\site-packages (from packaging->pytest) (2.4.7)
============================= test session starts =============================
platform win32 -- Python 3.8.6, pytest-6.2.0, py-1.10.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: D:\a\cloudresumechallenge-BackEnd\cloudresumechallenge-BackEnd
collected 0 items

============================ no tests ran in 0.31s ============================
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.```
````

Comment: What does your folder structure look like? How many tests do you have? Could you provide a sample test case?

Comment: `collected 0 items` indicates that most probably you don't have any tests. Pytest only considers functions whose name starts with `test_` or classes whose name starts with `Test` and has methods with name starting with `test_`. For example, `lambda_handler()`  is not a test and will be skipped.

Comment: BTW your GH actions workflow is messy - sometimes there's a `python -m pip` used, sometimes just `pip` and sometimes `pip3`, also `pytest` is installed twice. Better select a convetion and stick to it to avoid obscure errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should make sure that your test cases start with `test_` from the given data it seems to me that you didn't properly set up tests. For example, this is the correct structure for your app.

- MyApp/

  - run.py
  - tests/

    - test_function_1.py

Inside `test_function_1.py` you should have:

```py
# Just for the sake of the example
def test_func_case_1():
    assert True
def test_func_case_2():
    assert 1 == 1
```

Check this code and tell me if it helped you.